# Custom template content areas go missing when you exit the editor and go back in

Tags: email, visualforce-template

I have built a custom template that others can use without know how to code, however the template looks normal until content is dragged in and you exit the editor. When you go back into the editor the content areas are scrambled all over the place and some are missing. The code is validated and should be fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
The issue resolved when I removed `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` from the email template `<head>` tag.